# Unix Timestamp in Apache Combined Log?

Tags: logging, apache-2.2, time

So basic question, but I can't seem to find an easy answer.

How do I record the date/time in my apache logs to have a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch).

I have the default LogFormat as:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
```

Answer (score 4):

[Apache Module mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat):

```
%{format}t  The time, in the form given by format, which should be in strftime(3) format. (potentially localized)
```

Example:

```
    LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %{%s}t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common
    CustomLog /var/log/test vhost_common
```

Log:

```
127.0.1.1 127.0.0.1 - - 1309405372 "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 177
```